# Why use char padding[8]

Tags: c++, sizeof, chromium-embedded

```
template <typename T, typename U> class IsSubclass {
    typedef char YesType;
    struct NoType {
        char padding[8];
    };

    static YesType subclassCheck(U*);
    static NoType subclassCheck(...);
    static T* t;
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(subclassCheck(t)) == sizeof(YesType);
};
```

Why the size of the padding array should be 8 instead of other sizes？

I wish to know the reason for using 8

Comment: this code uses old techniques that are not needed anymore. Why the author choose `8` is unclear, and the name `padding` for the member is misleading imho.

Comment: When the YesType has size 1, the NoType should have any size other than 1. Size 8 works for that. No other reason. And also, you could use [std::is_base_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) and not have to bother with this kind of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be outdated code. Since C++11, there is [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of). Also, this approach of writing a type trait using two overloads with different `sizeof` for their return types is rather old-fashioned. I could fill a whole answer to explain the history and evolution of how to write such a type trait. However, I think that is beyond the scope of this question.

It works like this: The `T* t;` member is passed to the `subclassCheck()` member method. Either `t` can be implicitly converted to `U*`. This is the case when `U` is a public base class of `T`. Then `YesType subclassCheck(U*);` is called.

If `U` is not a public base class of `T`, then `t` cannot be converted to `U*` and `NoType subclassCheck(...);` is called.

`value` is the result of comparing the size of the return type of the called member function with the size of `YesType`. If they match, you know that `YesType subclassCheck(U*);` was called and that `T` inherits from `U`. Because `sizeof` is an un-evaluated context, no function is actually called (that's why it is OK to have only declarations, no definitions of the member functions).

This only works when `sizeof(NoType)` is different from `sizeof(YesType)`. What `NoType` actually contains is irrelevant as long as it makes `sizeof(NoType)` different from `sizeof(char)`.

There are many details that could be updated with newer C++ standards. `typedef` -> [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias). [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) rather than using `sizeof` to compare the types. And much more, but the whole approach is outdated. And also, C++11 introduced [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).